# Edit previous output to use in next command in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need to pull a certain string from a command output in a batch file, I am trying to get the GUID of the active power scheme to query the settings.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('powercfg /getactivescheme') DO set scheme=%%i
powercfg /query %scheme%
```

but of course the powercfg /getactivescheme command adds other useless junk to the output, so I end up with

```
C:\Users\Richard\Desktop>FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('powercfg /getactivescheme') DO
 set scheme=%i

C:\Users\Richard\Desktop>set scheme=Power Scheme GUID: c0ea6ad3-6145-4447-a15e-5
fb97be69b98  (Energy Star)
```

Now, all I want to pull is: `c0ea6ad3-6145-4447-a15e-5fb97be69b98` and truncate the `Power Scheme GUID:` and `(Energy Star)`

for input into the next command which is `powercfg /query %scheme%`

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the 4th token, separated by space/tabs

```
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%i IN ('powercfg /getactivescheme') DO set scheme=%%i
```